# Dagger2: cannot find symbol class Dagger*Component

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am looking into this example: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-MVP-Sample-Application

When I try to convert that project to Kotlin by clicking on --> Code --> Convert Java file to Kotlin file for some files..

I get:

**error: cannot find symbol class DaggerActivityComponent**
for BaseActivity.java

**error: cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationComponent** for MyApplication.java

Whats wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're using `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` in your build.gradle for `dagger-compiler`

Comment: If you use `kapt`, also don't forget to `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following in `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
…
dependencies {
    …
    final dagger_version = '2.17'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
}
```

For a complete step by step guide, see https://medium.com/@xiwei/simplest-dagger-example-920bbd10258